# Number eight does not work on the keyboard

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard

I am using Dell laptop with Windows 10.

Suddenly 'number eight' key does not work on the keyboard.
If I enter the key between '7' and '9', the slash (/) is entered instead of number eight.

What's wrong with my laptop?

Comment: Does this happen in another OS? (like live CD Linux).

Comment: I'm guessing your dell laptop have a dedicated numeric keypad? Spilled anything on it recently?

Comment: @Darius Dedicated numeric keypad --> No.  Spilled something --> No.

Comment: @user67275 You won't have a pranker in your place that may run/install something like this http://www.snapfiles.com/get/mapkeyboard.html and remap your keys...? Beyond that, try Kamil's suggestion to load a LiveCD/LiveUSB - running a fresh OS and see if its still happening. If it still happening in a different OS - you might end up with hardware issue

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski When I ran Ubuntu on VirtualBox, the key 'number eight' appears as 'number zero'

Comment: I meant you should temporarily move your current OS out of the way. Running Ubuntu on VirtualBox on the current OS doesn't do this.

Comment: Did you try to use On-Screen keyboard?

Comment: What model computer is it?